# How to retrieve data from a SQLite database and put them in unidimensional String Array?

Tags: android

My Android Application, I want to put new data in a table created in SQLite database,  but before that I want to avoid duplication. The way I want to do is first of all to retrieve the data from database and then I save it in a unidimensional String array, and then I run the array to check if the data i want to add into database is in that string, if yes then the data will not be reinserted, if no, then the data is inserted.

My main problem is to get all of those data and to put them into string array: below are my code which is giving only the last item in the database:

```
Cursor time_from_db=sqLite_database_helper_class.getting_all_call_logs_from_database();

            int i,n=time_from_db.getCount();

            String[] call_times_array=new String[n];

            while (time_from_db.moveToNext()){

                for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
                    call_times_array[i] = time_from_db.getString(4);
                }
            }

            for (i=0;i<n;i++){
                text_view_call_log_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_call_log_id);
                text_view_call_log_id.setText(call_times_array[i]+"\n\n");
            }
```

Whenever  I run this code, is showing that the record saved in that string array is the last one from the database while is a database containing 500 records. So please, kindly help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text_view_call_log_id.setText(call_times_array[i]+"\n\n");
```

This code will only show the last item as you are not appending it correctly. Please use the following code to append correctly.

```
String result = "";
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    result += call_times_array[i]+"\n\n";
}
text_view_call_log_id= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_call_log_id);
text_view_call_log_id.setText(result);
```

For retrieving data from cursor replace your `while` loop as follows

```
int i=0;
while (time_from_db.moveToNext()){
    call_times_array[i] = time_from_db.getString(4);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Fashed for the intervention; I have just tried that code you showed me and it seems to show the results from that string array, but the problem is this: That last record from the database is the only one which is put in that array 500 times. Maybe my code of retrieving data and putting it in that array is incorrect. Please could you possibly help me?

Comment: you will have to share your code for saving into the database

Comment: Here are my codes of saving into database @Fashed  ` //codes of saving call logs in database sqLite_database_helper_class=new SQLite_database_helper_class(HomePage.this); boolean call_logs_is_inserted =sqLite_database_helper_class.saving_call_logs (phone_number,real_name,dir,call_day_time.toString(),call_duration); if (call_logs_is_inserted==true){Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,"Log is saved successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }else {
                    Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,"Sorry!!! Failed to save logs.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } `

Comment: My mistake. Can you please update your question with the code of getting_all_call_logs_from_database method?

Comment: ` public Cursor getting_all_call_logs_from_database(){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor results=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+table_name,null);
        return results;
    }  `

Comment: you don't need to use for loop within your while loop. please check my updated answer for code.

Comment: Thank you very much my brother @Fashed this is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should append strings all you want to get.

Cursor time_from_db=sqLite_database_helper_class.getting_all_call_logs_from_database();

```
        int i,n=time_from_db.getCount();

        String[] call_times_array=new String[n];

        while (time_from_db.moveToNext()){

            for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
                call_times_array[i] = time_from_db.getString(4);
            }
        }
String result = "";
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    result += call_times_array[i]+"\n\n";
}
            text_view_call_log_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_call_log_id);
            text_view_call_log_id.setText(result );
```

Comment: Thank you @pppwang for the intervention; I have just tried that code you showed me and it seems to show the results from that string array, but the problem is this: That last record from the database is the only one which is put in that array 500 times. Maybe my code of retrieving data and putting it in that array is incorrect. Please could you possibly help me?

Comment: int i,n=time_from_db.getCount();

    String[] call_times_array=new String[n];
    int numIndex = 0;
    
    while (time_from_db.moveToNext()){
        call_times_array[numIndex] = time_from_db.getString(4);
        ++numIndex;
    }

    String result = "";
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        result += call_times_array[i]+"\n\n";
    }
    text_view_call_log_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_call_log_id);
    text_view_call_log_id.setText(call_times_array[i]+"\n\n");

Answer (score 0):

try this one?

```
int i,n=time_from_db.getCount();

String[] call_times_array=new String[n];
int numIndex = 0;

while (time_from_db.moveToNext()){
    call_times_array[numIndex] = time_from_db.getString(4);
    ++numIndex;
}

String result = "";
for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    result += call_times_array[i]+"\n\n";
}
text_view_call_log_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_call_log_id);
text_view_call_log_id.setText(call_times_array[i]+"\n\n");
```